# Do only oil derricks cost electric power?

Tags: warzone-2100

I was reading this [manual](http://guide.wz2100.net/power), it tells me one power generator can support up to for oil derricks, so that means other structure doesn't require power, am I wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the manual means is that any ONE power generator can only take input from up to four derricks.

Look at your generator when you build each new derrick, you'll see another glowing light orbit the central spire, up to four when the spire is 'full'.

If you want to build and use more than four, build a second generator.